# What is the hierarchy of Object.prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I didn't understand the output of the following code.

```
var obj = {}
console.log(Object);
console.log(Object.__proto__);
console.log(obj.prototype);
```

Output:

```
ƒ Object() { [native code] }

ƒ () { [native code] }

undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the three cases on by one

```
console.log(Object); // ƒ Object() { [native code] }
```

The above code return you a function because `Object` is a constructor function defined in Javascript that is used to create object properties

```
console.log(Object.__proto__); // ƒ () { [native code] }
```

The example above returns a function because `Object.__proto__` will be the same as `Function.prototype` which gives

[image]

```
console.log(obj.prototype); // undefined
```

The above code returns undefined because, the prototype property is not defined for the object that is created explicitly. The prototype property is defined for the constructor function and hence `Object.prototype` will give you `Objects` prototype which which the same as `obj.__proto__`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype && Function.prototype.__proto__.constructor === Object
```

it's a cyclic linkage. All functions 'inherit' from `Function` and all objects 'inherit' from `Object`. All objects are created from constructor functions and ,interestingly, all constructor functions are objects. So, what was first created an object or a function? Neither one. The programmer created them both from thin air and wrote creation statements in the engine code.

`Object`, `Function`, `Array` are built-in constructor functions.

`__proto__` (which is equal to `__proto__.constructor.prototype`) and `prototype` are objects.

since `__proto__` 'inherits' from Object, all functions (and almost anything in JavaScript) `inherit` indirectly from Object.

* by 'inherit' I mean delegating to an object's constructor prototype in case where a property is not found directly on the object itself